# Is it possible to only server side render certain pages in angular with angular universal?

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular10

I have a project where we use Angular Universal to server side render our public pages. Is it possible to prevent our non-public pages (ones that require login to access) from being server side rendered or to tell them to rely on the platform browser instead without injecting PLATFORM_ID and checking for isPlatformBrowser in every component?

Comment: You can modify `server.ts` to return `index.html` for routes that do not need to be prerendered

Comment: Thank you very much! That did the trick :)